# regex search is not catching what it should

Tags: python, regex, string

So I have to get part of a known string string. I use `re.search` for this. But in this specific circumstance, it is not catching what it should:

```
>>> a = 'c$}ononetentonemotw{$ore'
>>> b = 'c$}on(.*)tent(.*)mo(.*)re'
>>> c = re.search(b,a)
>>> c.groups()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

`c.groups()` should return: `('one','one','tw{$o')`, yet it does not actually catch this pattern, Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dollar sign is a special character in regular expressions, meaning "end of line".  You need to escape it:

```
b = r'c\$}on(.*)tent(.*)mo(.*)re'
```

Comment: Oh, okay so the dollar sign is there because I need to replace parentheses with something so I can do re.search the way I am...what are symbols that mean nothing in regex or python that would be good to use for this? (I use str.replace to put the parentheses back after I do re.search)

Comment: @Ryan Saxe: Read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for the `re` module to see what the special characters are.